# android:inputType="textAutoComplete" doesn't work

Tags: android, material-design

`TextAutoComplete` doesn't work in `TextInputLayout` from last version of `appcompat.design` library in Android.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/comment_title">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:hint="Заголовок"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:inputType="text|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textAutoComplete"
        >
    </EditText>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: "TextAutoComplit doesn't work". what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: It no errors, Android does not offer words

Comment: Use AutoCompleteTextView instead EditText.

Comment: @IllyaBublyk Did you solve yet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) is a editable text field, it displays a list of suggestions in a drop down menu from which user can select only one suggestion or value.
so use `AutoCompleteTextView` instead `EditText` .I hope it helps you .
For demo purpose please check [android-autocompletetextview-example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example)

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `AutoCompleteTextView` instead of normal `EditText`.

Here you can find an example.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html